# Facebook Marketing API: delete() vs. deleteSelf() in PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

What is the difference between `delete()` and `deleteSelf()` methods in Facebook Marketing API? [Campaign documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group#Deleting) now uses `deleteSelf()` as an example, but it was `delete()` before.

`delete()` is method of `AbstractArchivableCrudObject` abstract class, while `deleteSelf()` is method defined for each entity (like campaign, adset, ad) separately.

I'm struggling to use `deleteSelf()` though, getting missing API error, even though it seems to be properly instantiated (all other functionalities work):

```
$campaign = new \FacebookAds\Object\Campaign(
    $campaignId,
    null,
    new \FacebookAds\Api(
        new \FacebookAds\Http\Client,
        new \FacebookAds\Session($appId, $appSecret, $accessToken)
    )
);

$campaign->deleteSelf();
```

The error is:

> An Api instance must be provided as argument or set as instance in the \FacebookAds\Api

If I replace `$campaign->deleteSelf()` with `$campaign->delete()`, it works without any problem.

What's the deal about `deleteSelf()`?

Answer (score 0):

**deleteSelf** makes an api request and returns an object Response.
You can get info from this request, for example:

```
$deleted = $campaign->deleteSelf();
$body = json_decode($deleted->getBody(), TRUE);
echo $body['success'];
```

**delete** returns nothing